# Is lodash _.size() faster than JS length property?

Tags: javascript, size, lodash

The article (link below) suggests that using the length property on a string creates an object reference which unnecessarily slows the function down.

http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/jkm3/2.html

In this context, what is the advantage of using lodash _.size() ?  Does it perform any differently than the (native...?) length property?

If you're counting an array or keys in an object, is there any benefit to using lodash size instead of the length property?

Comment: I was suspicious about the conclusion in that article, so I tried reproducing the benchmark and I did not get a comparable result; the times I get are 2.25 and 2.14 microseconds. I suspect the author ran their tests quite some time ago and used what is now a very slow machine, a very outdated JavaScript implementation, or both. This is not something that I would worry about now.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From the lodash sources, `_.size()` is implemented as:

```
function size(collection) {
  var length = collection ? getLength(collection) : 0;
  return isLength(length) ? length : keys(collection).length;
}
```

For an array, the first line is indirectly doing `collection.length` so that `_.size()` is, if anything, a little (tiny) bit slower.

In the performance article, the performance problem is that the property lookup of `length` is being used when a number on the stack could have been used to achieve the same goal. In other words, the solution was not to look for a faster property, but to avoid the property altogether when it could be done.

Answer (score 28):

The [size()](https://lodash.com/docs#size) function is most useful in chains, when you need the size of the result. There's no point in unpacking everything using [value()](https://lodash.com/docs#prototype-value) just to get the size. For example:

```
_(_.range(10))
    .filter(function(item) { return item % 2; })
    .size();
```

As opposed to the longer form:

```
_(_.range(10))
    .filter(function(item) { return item % 2; })
    .value()
    .length;
```

This function also makes it easier to find the size of an object:

```
_.size({ a: 1, b: 2 });
```

As opposed to:

```
Object.keys({ a: 1, b: 2 }).length;
```

`size()` is about code brevity, not performance.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/17859/3/native-filterlength-vs-lodash-sumby-vs-lodash-filtersiz says that `array.filter(testFunction).length` is faster than using lodash like `_(array).filter(testFunction).size()` on Firefox and Chrome, as of 3/22/2022.

That link also shows an even faster method of doing the same thing. I assume that the even faster method is faster, because it doesn't bother to create a new array and add the filtered elements to that array, like the `filter()` does in `array.filter(testFunction).length`.